# PHP Display Array with Array_Slice

Tags: arrays, arraylist, array-key, slice

```
$array = array(
'name'      => 'john',
'age'       => '25',
'birthday'  => '02-03-1988',
'gender'    => 'male',
'telephone' => '98676878',
'location'  => 'Australia'
);

$array_slice = array_slice($array, 0, 3);

foreach($array_slice as $key => $val) {
  if($key !== 'age') {
  echo $key.' => '.$val.'<br>'; 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
name     => john
birthday => 02-03-1988
```

How to display 3 values of array?

So, I want output to be like this:

```
name     => john
birthday => 02-03-1988
gender   => male
```

I am very beginner in programmer, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  new solution after exchanging some comments below

You must filter the array and get the result in a new array. Then you display the content of the second array.

To filter your original array, use either [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) or [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear, that's just an example.. my array is more long and random.. but I know some key and I don't want to display it.. I use array_slice to create pagination..

Comment: I'm sorry too, because what you want to achieve is still not clear for me. Do you want to display all but some value, for which you know the key?

Comment: Yes, my array is files, I want to display all files but not for some file.. assume my files are 20, and I create 2 page list using array_slice (because it is too long), Page1 = 10 files and Page2 = 10 files, but my problem is when I hide some file, assume 3 files are hidden.. my page displays 7 files on Page1 and 10 files on Page2.. What I want is 10 files on Page1 and 7 files on Page2... anyway thanks for your help...